# GWT com.google.gwt.json.client.* JSON classes not supporting for jsinterop?

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop

When I try to compile and run the code

```
JSONValue jv = JSONParser.parseStrict(jsonString);
```

I got console message as following-

> [WARN] Some stale types ([com.mycompany.gwtjs.client.AjaxForm$1,
>   com.mycompany.gwtjs.client.AjaxForm$1$1,
>   com.mycompany.gwtjs.client.AjaxForm]) were not reprocessed as was
>   expected. This is either a compiler bug or a Generator has
>   legitimately stopped creating these types.

The link http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html has package which is having the classes i used.

Please anyone has having idea to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some detail on what AjaxForm is (and its inner types)? is it created by hand, or generated? If you're using JsInterop, consider using elemental2-dom's `Global.JSON.parse` instead, which is might simpler (and yet does the same thing) as `JSONParser.parseStrict`.

Comment: Please post the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your Solultion that works nicely.  

`The import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONArray;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONString;
and more...

also works, The problem was in  Project.gwt.xml configuration file. I did not inherit the JSON Module. After inheriting it, My earlier code runs. I would like to say how i fix this. I put -strict flag in complier running option. After that the complied asked to inherit the module. Anyway thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: `code`
JSONObject jsonObj = parsed.isObject();
         if (jsonObj != null) {
          for (String key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
           JSONValue jsonValue = jsonObj.get(key);
           if(jsonValue.isArray() != null) {
            GWT.log("Array values are not allowed in a key.");
            break;
           }

           JSONString jsonString =  jsonValue.isString();
           String strVal = jsonString.stringValue();
           if(strVal == null) strVal = "";
           requestBuilder.setHeader(key, strVal);
          }
         }

`code`

Comment: Can you put the code in the question? And how does this relate to your AjaxForm type (and its two nested inner types)?